# Populate field depending on which button in a loop has been clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom loop using Advanced Custom Fields which displays three boxes each with content.

If the button in box 1 has been selected, I want the content in box 1 to populate into the input.

If the button in box 2 has been selected, I want the content in box 2 to populate into the input and so on.

My html is below:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php if( have_rows('event') ): while ( have_rows('event') ) : the_row(); ?>
        <div class="four">
            <div class="input"><?php the_sub_field('details'); ?></div>
            <a class="button btn" href="#contact">Make an appointment</a>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; else : endif; ?>
</div>

<input id="output"></input>
```

And my jQuery is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".btn").click(function(e) {
        $("#output").val($(".input").val());    
    });
});
```

I have managed to find working solutions for one box but not for a loop, I suspect it might be something do with .each() but I am not sure.

Thanks.

Comment: If `.input` is a div, how is `.val()` working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your jQuery is very close.

There are two issues:

1. You are attempting to use the `.val()` of a `div`, which doesn't have a `value` - it has `text` (or html), so you need to use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) (or [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)).  In your case, I believe `.text` is what you are after.
2. You are putting the value if the *first* `.input` element into the input, when you want the `.input` that is related to the button clicked.  There's a couple of ways to do this, but in your case, the most direct would be to use [.siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

   ```
   // Short-hand document ready (which is no-conflict safe, necessary in WP scripts)  
   jQuery(function($) {
       $(".btn").click(function(e) {
           // $(this) is this button - get the sibling .input element's text
           $("#output").val($(this).siblings(".input").text());    
       });
   });
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am still learning jQuery but the way you have explained makes sense to me and works like a charm! Really appreciate the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get the sibling input of the clicked button. However, you do need to make your `div class="input"` an actual `input` for `.val()` to work. Otherwise, you will have to use `.text()` to get the text in the div.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".btn").click(function(e) {
        $("#output").val($(this).siblings('.input').val());    
    });
});
```

Comment: @cale_b Hence "you do need to make your `div class="input" an actual `input` for `.val()` to work." A div can have a value, but that's not something you typically you do.

Comment: @Gavin `value` is not a valid attribute for a `<div>` element

Comment: @j08691 If you're referring to my answer, you should read the actual text before the code. If you're referring to my comment, I know that it's not valid, but it does work.